# Depth of registry tree

Tags: windows-registry

When it comes to Windows registry, it can get max. 512 levels deep, right? But the key-name itself can only be max. 255 characters long, right? Each new level of depth adds one backslash character to a key-name. Therefore if a key-name consisted of backslash characters only (which is not possible), it would only get 255 levels deep (or so), which is nowhere near the limit of 512. Something I do not understand?

So what is the actual max. depth of the registry tree? It is clearly less than 512

Comment: I haven't checked if the numbers you've provided are correct, but assuming they are I can see where the error in your reasoning is: 255 characters is the limit for key name, not key path.

Answer (score 2):

Registry key functions such as RegOpenKeyEx() or NtOpenKey() take two parameters – the key path, and a handle to the base key to start looking from. The base key can be a "root" key such as HKEY_CURRENT_USER, but it *does not have to be* – you can use another previously opened subkey handle as the base.

So if you have a long path, you can walk it **incrementally**, first getting a handle to a subkey 150 levels deep, then using it as the base to descend 150 levels more (thus getting the handle of a 300-level-deep key), and so forth, until eventually you reach the last path component.

File access works the same way – by using the "current" directory as the base, you can reach paths longer than you could specify directly. (In fact some systems have file APIs that allow the base handle to be specified explicitly, instead of only having one "current directory" – see for example Linux openat().)

---

In addition, some path length limits only apply to the "Win32" functions, but not to the lower-level "native NT" functions that Win32 is built upon. Programs could directly call NT API functions if they wanted to do something that's impossible at the Win32 layer, and this sometimes includes the ability to use longer paths.